# Stored procedure for INSERT doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Here you can see my code for a table in SQL, the stored procedures are working but the rows are not filled with the information. What's wrong with the code?

```
CREATE TABLE Category_Master(
    Category_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Category_Name VARCHAR(50),
    modification_Date DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

Select * from Category_Master
Go

create trigger TRIGGER_MODIFDATE_Category_Master
on Category_Master
for insert, update 
as begin 
    UPDATE Category_Master 
    SET modification_Date = GETDATE()
end 
Go

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertCategory_Master
    @flag bit output,-- return 0 for fail,1 for success
    @Category_ID int,
    @Category_Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION 
  BEGIN TRY 
       INSERT INTO Category_Master(Category_ID, Category_Name) 
       VALUES (@Category_ID, @Category_Name)

       SET @flag = 1;

       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       BEGIN 
           COMMIT TRANSACTION;
       END
  END TRY 
  BEGIN CATCH
       IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
       BEGIN 
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
       END

       SET @flag = 0;
  END CATCH
END 
Go

Declare @flag bit

EXEC usp_InsertCategory_Master @flag output, 1, 'Short LOAN'
EXEC usp_InsertCategory_Master @flag output, 2, 'Long LOAN'

if @flag=1
  print 'Successfully inserted'
else
  print 'There is some error'
```

Comment: YOur trigger is bad too, it will update all records not just the ones you inserted or updated. YOu need to join to the inserted table to get only the records affected by teh insert or update.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert values into an identity column. You do not enter anything into it and it will populate a value automatically. You code is failing because of this.

If you do want to be able to do this either define the column as thus:

`Category_ID INT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY`

or you can disable the identity column during insert:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx